# Line Generator not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to create a parallel coordinates chart. However, I am having trouble with the line generator. When I run my code, I see two path elements are created in the right place and with the class attribute. Also as a sanity check, I just added this `a` attribute to see if the data is correct (it is!).

However, the SVG path is not generated by my line generator. In fact, the `d` attribute is not added to the path element at all.

```
var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain(d3.range(dimensions.length))
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain([0, 1])
  .range([0, height]);

var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .x( function(d){xScale(d.u);} )
  .y( function(d){yScale(d.c);} )

a = [
      {"u":0, "c":0.1},
      {"u":1, "c":0.2},
    ]

    foreground = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "foreground")
  .selectAll("path")
    .data(a)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("a", function(d){return [d.u, d.c];})
      .attr("d", lineGenerator)
      ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Two main problems.

First, you have to return the values in your line generator:

```
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.u);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.c);
  });
```

Second, your data method is incorrect. It should be:

```
.data([a])
```

Or, alternatively, drop the enter selection and just use `datum` (if you have just one path):

```
foreground = svg.append("path")
  .datum(a)
  //etc...
```

Yet another option is passing the string directly to the `d` attribute (also if you have just one path):

```
foreground = svg.append("path")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .attr("d", lineGenerator(a));
```

Finally, check those scales. I bet that `scalePoint` is not what you want for the `y` axis.